# reverse chunks in a file

Tags: java, algorithm

My basic Java problem is this: I need to read in a file by chunks, then reverse the order of the chunks, then write that out to a new file.  My first (naive) attempt followed this approach:

1. read a chunk from the file.
2. reverse the bytes of the chunk
3. push the bytes one at a time to the front of a results list
4. repeat for all chunks
5. write result list to new file.

So this is basically a very stupid and slow way to solve the problem, but generates the correct output that I am looking for.  To try to improve the situation, I change to this algorithm:

1. read a chunk from the file
2. push that chunk onto the front of a list of arrays
3. repeat for all chunks
4. foreach chunk, write to new file

And to my mind, that produces the same output.  except it doesn't and I am quite confused. The first chunk in the result file matches with both methods, but the rest of the file is completely different.

Here is the meat of the Java code I am using:

```
FileInputStream in;
FileOutputStream out, out2;

Byte[] t = new Byte[0];
LinkedList<Byte> reversed_data = new LinkedList<Byte>();
byte[] data = new byte[bufferSize];
LinkedList<byte[]> revd2 = new LinkedList<byte[]>();

try {
in = new FileInputStream(infile);
out = new FileOutputStream(outfile1);
out2 = new FileOutputStream(outfile2);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return;
}
while(in.read(data) != -1)
{
    revd2.addFirst(data);
    byte[] revd = reverse(data);
    for (byte b : revd)
    {
        reversed_data.addFirst(b);
    }
}
for (Byte b : reversed_data)
{
    out.write(b);
}
for (byte[] b : revd2)  
{
    out2.write(b);
}
```

At http://pastie.org/3113665 you can see a complete example program (a long with my debugging attempts). For simplicity I am using a bufferSize that divides evenly the size of the file so all chunks will be the same size, but this won't hold in the real world.  My question is, WHY don't these two methods generate the same output?  It's driving me crazy because I can't grok it.

Comment: Is this a homework assignment? I am just wondering what the larger context of the problem is.

Comment: My first baby footsteps in signal processing.  The data is a PCM stream.

Comment: So, I am confused: is the assignment to reverse all bytes in the file, or is it to just reverse the order of the chunks?

Comment: Are you sure it is safe to assume that you have enough memory to fit the entire file in it?

Comment: What are the two output files for?

Comment: @MikeNakis the job is to reverse the chunks.  There is an output file for each method I am using.  It is certainly NOT safe to assume there will be enough memory for the entire file, but I know how to solve that problem when I need to.  What I don't understand is why these two methods are generating different outputs.

Comment: Well, if the job is to reverse the chunks, then why are you also reversing the bytes? Then again, if this is a PCM stream, then I would think that you would want to reverse the bytes, not just the chunks, if the output is to have any meaning whatsoever. (Looking for satanic verses in Rock songs.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're constantly overwriting the data you've read previously.

```
while(in.read(data) != -1)
{
    revd2.addFirst(data);
    // ignore byte-wise stuff
}
```

You're adding the same object repeatedly to the list `revd2`, so each list node will finally contain a reference to `data` filled with the result of the last `read`. I suggest replacing that with `revd2.addFirst(data.clone())`.

Comment: THANK YOU, that was driving me crazy.  can't believe i didn't see that.

Comment: Of course, `data.clone()` is in the original order, so you would still have to do what I suggested, making `data.clone()` redundant. ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey No, the aim was to reverse the order of chunks, while keeping the byte order in each chunk. The original byte-wise code reverses each chunk twice, once per `reverse` and then by pushing each byte to the fron of the big list.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you want to change

```
revd2.addFirst(data);
byte[] revd = reverse(data);
```

for the following so the reversed copy is added to the start of the list.

```
byte[] revd = reverse(data);
revd2.addFirst(revd);
```

Comment: @MikeNakis the second half is my answer. Perhaps I added it later. ??

Comment: The first approach reverses a chunk twice, first the chunk is reversed by this function i wrote, reverse(), which you can see on pastie.org and then it reverses it again when it pushes each byte to the front of the result list.

Comment: @Segfault I understand you are doing it two different ways. One way for `out` and a second way for `out2`

Comment: yes, but what i was trying to say in this comment was that the first approach reverses each chunk twice, so that the chunk is in the same order as it was read.  The second approach doesn't reverse the chunks at all.

Comment: @Segfault in that case my guess was correct, ignore the rest. Creating a clone() or adding it won't help you.

Comment: Sorry I didn't state the problem clearly enough, the chunks themselves should be unmodified.

Comment: In that case, you can just clone the data for the amount actually read. At the end of the file you won't have a full block, so you have the decide what you want to do there.